# R function to populate a vector

Tags: r, function

I want to populate a vector with item returned by a function. but I am not being able to do this

```
w=NULL
fn=function(x){

for (i in x){ if (i%%2==1){ w <- c(w, i) 
 } print (w)

} return (w) }
```

after executing `fn (c(1,3,4,7,8,9))`

I still get

```
w NULL
```

what I was expecting is

```
w [1] 1 3 7 9
```

Comment: your function produces errors

Comment: You don't need all this looping etc - `test <- c(1,3,4,7,8,9); fn <- function(x) x[x %% 2 ==1]; fn(test)`

Answer (score 1):

This works as R code, but is it what you're expecting?

```
w <- NULL

fn <- function(x){

    for(i in x){ 

        if(i%%2==1){
            w <- c(w, i) 
        } 
        print (w)
    }
return (w)
}

x <- c(1,3,4,7,8,9)
fn(x)
# [1] 1
# [1] 1 3
# [1] 1 3
# [1] 1 3 7
# [1] 1 3 7
# [1] 1 3 7 9
# [1] 1 3 7 9
```

---

Do you in fact just want

```
x[x%%2==1]
# [1] 1 3 7 9
```

Answer (score 1):

Usually the `w` you want to use **inside** your function is different than the one you use **outside** in your R session (despite both being called the same). That is why your function does not change the `w` in your R session after being executed and it stays as NULL.

If you really want to change the value of your `w` in the R session within the function you can use the assignment `<<-`

```
w = NULL
fn = function (x) {
    for (i in x) {
        if (i %% 2 == 1) {
            w <<- c (w, i)  ## here is the change
        }
        print (w)
    }
    return (w) # and this is not strictly needed
}

fn (c(1,3,4,7,8,9))

w
```

[1] 1 3 7 9

Comment: I don't think your reason is **why** the `w` isn't changed. Lexical scoping would mean the `w` would get changed as it is in the enclosing environment